# Fatal Error - 'Mongo' class not found

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, installation, wamp

I'm trying to execute this:

```
<?php

// connect
$m = new Mongo();

?>
```

But I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\wamp\www.....

---

#### Info:

- PHP: 5.38
- MongoDB: mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2
- MongoDB PHP Driver: mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc6ts
- WampServer: 2.2
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

I've followed the MongoDB installation fine (incl. adding the DLL to ext & php.ini), I've started mongod.exe and WAMP is running.

#### What does this imply is missing/incorrect?

---

## Edit:

I have got it running on another Windows 7 machine (Windows 7 Profressional). That got me curious. So now my Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 machine has the same `http.conf`, `php.ini`, `C:\wamp\bin\mongodb` contents (therefore DBs are the exact same) and the exact same batch file to start `mongod.exe` as my Win7 Professional machine.

But still, all I can do on my Win7 Enterprise SP1 machine is connect via command line. My Win7 Professional machine's `phpinfo()` contains:
[image: Mongo section in php.ini]
My Win7 Enterprise SP1 machine doesn't contain any reference to MongoDB.

The contents of the batch file I use to start MongoDB:

```
"C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe" --logpath "C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\logs\error.log" --logappend --dbpath "C:\wamp\bin\mongodb\data\db" --directoryperdb --service
Net Start "MongoDB"
pause
```

Comment: did you restart apache? also check if you edited correct `php.ini` (the one indicated by `phpinfo()` as loaded`

Comment: @Mchl Yes I restarted and yes I edited the correct `php.ini` according to `phpinfo()`

Comment: Just to check: for www php.ini is in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\bin`. For CLI php.ini is at `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8`

Comment: @Mchl `phpinfo()` says the `php.ini` that's loaded is at `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini` and that's the one I've added `extension=php_mongo.dll` to.

Comment: That should be fine. I'm not sure what else to look at.

Comment: Did you ever get this working Adam?

Comment: @TylerBrock No not yet. Might try install PHP, MySql & Apache separately. But I don't really want to. If I could just `require()` in the Mongo php file needed I'd prefer it

Comment: @TylerBrock and everyone else: I've added a bit more to the question, including errors returned by `mongod.exe` from the command line. Check it out. Apparently `data\db` doesn't exist, but it does

Comment: make sure it's on c: as in c:\data\db\, also you can specify your own path via --dbpath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the PHP driver (`php_mongo.dll`). Apache/WAMP just did not like the `mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc6ts` version for some reason. My Windows 7 Professional machine had the `mongo-1.2.5-php5.3vc9ts` version. That was the only difference between the two machines.

I originally had been using the `mongo-1.2.5-php5.3vc9ts` version of the driver on the Windows 7 Enterprise machine but changed to the `mongo-1.1.4-php5.3vc6ts`version when I was troubleshooting the problem. So the original problem could actually just have been that the database path `data\db` didn't exist/couldn't be found (and needed to be specified using `--dbpath` when running/starting `mongod.exe`).

Comment: This is very tricky because you got to install `php_mongo.dll` and not `php_mongodb.dll`. 2 packages are present in PECL library. Also vc6 and vc9 require a proper C++ Redistributable library installed. Version x86 or x64 depends on the compiled version of Apache

Answer (score 5):

If this problem exist in php CLI you should add `extension=mongo.so` to your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file

Answer (score 0):

Check out the exact compiler name of your PHP binary in phpinfo page and try to reinstall the mongo driver was built on same compiler.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

You're using the mongo driver was bulit on Visual Studio 6 with Thread-safe, now. ( vs6ts means it )

Similar problem was caused by compiler issue;

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#104223

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, I used [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) . Once installed, echo the phpinfo() and check if the mongo.ini file is located in the correct directory mentioned in phpinfo with  'Scan this dir for additional .ini files'