# Unable to connect mongo db server from php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed the mongo db server and i have run the server from the command prompt administrator up to installing the mongo db server and running the mongo db server was fine.

when i have to install the mongo db php driver

the specifications mentioned by the php mongo db server i have done...here i am placing my details what needs

PHP Version 5.6.12

Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)

Zend Extension Build    API220131226,TS,VC11

PHP Extension Build API20131226,TS,VC11

i have choosen the **php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11-nts** and renamed it as **php_mongo** and placed in php extension folder
and in php.ini file written **extension=php_mongo.dll** after that i have restarted my xampp server

even though it is giving the following error

```
     Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 3
```

please suggest anyone

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error - 'Mongo' class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927255/fatal-error-mongo-class-not-found)

Comment: i did'nt get brother

Comment: Did you start the mongod server? In windows you have to manually start the mongod server by default. Also, you have to set the PATH for libsasl.dll which is inside your php installation directory. See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) for more information