# include(Mongo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am using Yii 1.1 and when I run the root page index.php
Yii::createWebApplication($env->configWeb)->run();
it shows error: `"include(Mongo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"` in YiiBase.php(441)

[image]

I have db config here:

```
'import' => [
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.services.*',
    'ext.directmongosuite.components.*',
    'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.*',
],

 'behaviors' => [
    'edms' => [
    'class'=>'EDMSBehavior',
    ],
  ],

  'modules' => [
  ],

 // application components
 'components' => [
    'user' => [
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
     'edms' => [
     'class' => 'EDMSConnection',
     'dbName' => 'mic',
     'server' => 'mongodb://localhost.localdomain:27017', 
     'options' => [
        'replicaSet' => false, 
        'connect' => true,
        'timeout' => 5000,
    ],
```

I have tried to dowload the php mongo extensions add extension=mongo.so to the php.ini file in both /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini but it still doesn't work!!

[image]

Comment: Not sure it has something to do with php's mongo extension, you can probably try to check if you have it installed from outside of Yii itself. This looks more like an "class autoloading" problem. You're trying to instantiate a class called "Mongo", and Yii cannot find it anywhere. Maybe there's some issue either with your code, or with the extensions you're importing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error - 'Mongo' class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927255/fatal-error-mongo-class-not-found)